# Get parameter names from MS Access query in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access, oledb

I have this C# code that gets the first query from an MDB file and executes it:

```
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=c:\\db1.mdb");
        conn.Open();
        DataTable dt = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Procedures, null);
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = dt.Rows[0]["PROCEDURE_DEFINITION"].ToString();
        cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

I get an error on the last line because I haven't given values for the required parameters.  I want this code to work with any query, with any number of parameters, so how can I get a list of parameters from Access, for the given query?  This way I can prompt the user to supply values for each one, like Access does.

I don't think I can just parse them myself, because a query might look like:

select * from Orders where [Name] = [Nickname]

Without knowing all of the field names for a table (gets really complex with lots of JOINS), I don't know if [Name] is a column in the table or a parameter that needs to be supplied, same with [Nickname].  I guess I could look up more schema info to get all of the field names... but hopefully there is an easier way?

I'm trying to create a Winforms .NET C# form that has a list of queries from a given MDB file.  The user can select any of these queries, and then I will display the results in a DataGridView.  In order to display the results, I need to execute the query, but I can't execute the query if I don't supply the correct parameters.

Comment: You want to use [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/860056/102937)

Comment: Guess that answers the "If I have to do it the hard way" question, and I'm guessing that is what I have to do.  Thanks.

Comment: It has the distinction of being straightforward and reliable.  Just use it ot write a function that accepts a connection and a table name, and returns a `List<string>` of names.