# How do I get a list of columns in an Access database using C#?

Tags: c#, ms-access

At runtime, how do I get the list of columns in a table in Access? I don't want the data in the table, just the column names and types.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I'm using C#.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get column names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343922/get-column-names)

Comment: tl;dr: `Set db = CurrentDb()
Set rs1 = db.OpenRecordset("Table1")
Dim fld As DAO.Field
For Each fld In rs1.Fields
'do stuff
Next`

Comment: can also see [the field object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193203(v=office.15).aspx) for what you can get back from it

Answer (score 2):

You want to iterate through the fields property of the table definition.  I've listed two ways you can loop through the property.

C# Solution (uses `System.Data` and `System.Data.OleDb`)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/864382/2448686

VBA Solution

```
Public Function GetTableDetails()
    Dim db As Database
    Dim td As TableDef

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set td = db.TableDefs("tableName")

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To td.Fields.Count - 1
        Debug.Print td.Fields(i).Type
    Next

    Dim f As Field
    For Each f In td.Fields
        Debug.Print f.Type
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: What library are you getting these objects from?

Comment: I believe if not explicitly stated otherwise, it defaults to DAO.

Comment: Better use `DAO` explicitly

Comment: @JonathanAllen I think the library in C# is `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access` and `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao`.  I will have to confirm a bit later.

Comment: I'd rather avoid anything in that namespace. I can't really count on them having office installed. Straight DAO via COM interopt, on the other hand, would be reasonable.

Comment: Then `System.Data` and `System.Data.OleDb` is what you're looking for.  I've added a link to a great C# solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using VBA:

```vb
dim db as DAO.Database, rs as DAO.Recordset, f as DAO.Field
set db = currentDb()
set rs = db.openRecordset("yourTable", dbOpenDynaset, dbReadOnly)
with rs
    for each f in rs.Fields
        ' Simple example: print to the inmediate window
        debug.print f.Name
    next f
end with
```

***Untested:*** Instead of a `Recordset` object, use a `TableDef` object:

```
dim db as DAO.Database, t as DAO.TableDef, f as DAO.Field
set db = currentDb()
set t = db.TableDefs("yourTable")
with t
    for each f in t.Fields
        debug.print f.name
    next f
end with
```

Comment: Um, wouldn't that send the whole table to the client?

Comment: @JonathanAllen Updated to address your concern. AFAIK when you use `dbOpenDynaset` rows are retreived when required (if you used `dbOpenSnapshot` the whole recordset would have to be loaded in RAM)